# Why use class AND element type in a CSS selector?

Tags: css

I am curious to know the usage of the `div.something` in CSS.  I have seen this around the Internet but don't know what it really means when people use `div.` following by some class without gaps. What is it?

```
div.report {
    background:pink;
}
```

This seems the same thing like `.report { .. }` so why would some one use `div.report`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div.report` means that only `div` elements with the class of `report` will be selected. `.report` on the other-hand will select any element with report class, be it a `div`, `p`, `span`, etc.

Additionally, `div.report` is more specific than `.report`, so properties in the former will override properties in the later.

Comment: This answer adds an important extra detail about specificity.

Answer (score 1):

This CSS rule matches `div` elements with the class `report`. If you omitted the div then it would match any element with the class `report`.

Comment: Right, I get it. It makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In case you also have `<span class="report">`.

Or, simply to clarify to people reading the CSS what elements will have that class.